# Angular dropdown passing values when i am not select?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, checkbox

[My demo](http://jsfiddle.net/yb2717v2/1/)

my expectation when i uncheck Samsung Galaxy S6 checkbox it should not show dropdown and .when i submit that button dropdown should not pass that id value 
becoze nothing is selected

now when i uncheck Samsung Galaxy S6 checkbox drop down is not showing but before i have selected some value in dropdown,when i submit i am getting that old selected value.

I have a list of checkboxes and, based on the checkbox value, select dropdown

When I check checkbox checked checkbox value its checking this `$scope.offer` object  checked model name is there or not. If whether checked model name is  there in `$scope.offer` object dropdown will come and it will show offer message.

If offer is not there for particular checkbox value dropdown will not come. But here problem is when I uncheck checkbox that particular checkbox (which is having offer) and submit that page, offer message drop down still passing value.

```js
function Test1Controller($scope) {
  var storeid = window.localStorage.getItem("storeid");
  var serverData = ["Samsung Galaxy Note", "Samsung Galaxy S6", "Samsung Galaxy Avant", "Samsung Galaxy Young"];
  $scope.items = [];
  $scope.selection = [];

  $scope.offers = [{
    id: "as23456",
    Store: "samsung",
    Offer_message: "1500rs off",
    modalname: "Samsung Galaxy Young"

  }, {
    id: "de34575",
    Store: "samsung",
    Offer_message: "20% Flat on Samsung Galaxy S6",
    modalname: "Samsung Galaxy S6"

  }, ]

  $scope.toggleSelection = function toggleSelection(item) {
    $scope.gotOffers = [];
    var idx = $scope.selection.indexOf(item);

    // is currently selected
    if (idx > -1) {
      $scope.selection.splice(idx, 1);
    }

    // is newly selected
    else {
      $scope.selection.push(item);
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.selection.length; i++) {
      for (var j = 0; j < $scope.offers.length; j++) {
        console.log($scope.selection[i].name + "   " + $scope.offers[j].modalname)
        if ($scope.selection[i].name == $scope.offers[j].modalname) {
          var idx = $scope.gotOffers.indexOf($scope.offers[j].Offer_message);
          if (idx == -1) {
            console.log("inside idx")
            $scope.gotOffers.push($scope.offers[j]);
          }

        }
      }

    }
    console.log($scope.offers);

  };

  var selectedvalue = window.localStorage.getItem("selectedvalue");
  // here selected value Samsung Galaxy S6
  var selectedvalue = "Samsung Galaxy S6";
  for (var i = 0; i < serverData.length; i++) {
    var modal = {
      name: serverData[i],
      selected: false
    };
    if (selectedvalue.indexOf(serverData[i]) >= 0 || null) {
      $scope.toggleSelection(modal);

    }
    $scope.items.push(modal);
  }
  //----------------------------Our Shop Offers----------------------------------------

  //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------



  //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  $scope.check = function()

  {

    console.log($scope.offerSelected);
      var checkedItems = [];
      for (var i = 0; i < $scope.selection.length; i++) {
        checkedItems.push($scope.selection[i].name);
      }
      console.log(checkedItems);
    }



  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.1.5/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app>
  <div ng-controller="Test1Controller">
    <div ng-repeat="item in items">
      <input type="checkbox" ng-checked="selection.indexOf(item) >= 0" ng-click="toggleSelection(item)" /> {{item.name}}
    </div>
    <select ng-show="gotOffers.length > 0" ng-model="offerSelected">
      <option ng-repeat="offer in gotOffers" value="{{offer.id}}">{{offer.Offer_message}}</option>
    </select>

    <input type="button" name="submit" value="submit" ng-click="check()" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: why don't you used `ng-model` instead of using `ng-checked`?

Comment: if i use ng-model .how can i push some value to make checkbox is checked in  checkbox list .l

Comment: can you check my fiddle @ Pankaj Parkar.just update your answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is doing this because your are not clearing `offerSelected` when you hide the select.

`ng-show` merely hides the element, it sets the style `display: none !important;` but doesn't modify any of the bindings related to your element. What would happen then if you wanted to show the select with the same data and selection?

When you empty the array in `toggleSelection` that you create the select from you should also empty the `ng-model`. If the value in the `ng-model` is not in the array you provide angular won't clear it. It will keep it but just not highlight that element in the select as it doesn't exist.

---

EDIT: As a side note you would find it much easier if you implemented your select with `ng-options`

---

Edit Again: As OP requested ive updated the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yb2717v2/2/

Heres the core bit. Seeing as you can have multiple checkboxes selected the element the user selects could still be present in the list when they select another option firing your `toggleSelection` method. So you can't just blindly empty `offerSelected`. You can only empty it if its not an available selection. (unless you want it to be emptied every time they click a check box that is.) It implements [array.some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) check the docs to ensure it is supported by the browsers you need.

```
/*
  array.some() will itterate over every element in the array callings its callback FN.
  If any FN returns true it will imedietly exit and return true. So you can use it 
  to check if the element exists in the array.
*/
var ElementExists = $scope.gotOffers.some(function (offer) {
    return ($scope.offerSelected && offer.id === $scope.offerSelected);
});

//If it doesn't exist clear the model
if (!ElementExists) {
    $scope.offerSelected = undefined;
}
```

I've also implemented `ng-options` in the fiddle.

Comment: send me the fiddle link

Comment: @martin look at my answer, ive added it for every one to see in case it may help others.